# PhoneGap: how skip inAppBrowser to open an url with Safari

Tags: ios, cordova, safari, inappbrowser

I have a Phonegap app on iOS and I use the InAppBrowser plugin to navigate some url.
Now in a specific case, I need to open full safari browser, but the plugin of course open the embedded one.
Anyone knows how to let an app to open either the embedded browser or the "full" Safari?

Thanks in advance

-Claudio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:::

```
            $('#btnVetResources').click(function( event ) {

                var myURL = encodeURI('https://www.google.co.in');
                window.open(myURL, '_system');
            });
```